# Associative Law for infinitely many sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, associativity

I know the associative law for (union or intersection) of two sets and I know why it works.

Applying this rule many times, will show us intuitively that this rule also holds for infinitely many sets.

Although, what would be an adequate proof for this generalization? Is it sufficient to say that we know that it works for two sets and it works for all the pairs, so it works for all sets?

Sorry for the confusion. Intuitively seems right, but I want to understand it formally. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathscr{A}$ is any family of sets, we can define

$$\bigcup\mathscr{A}=\{x:\exists A\in\mathscr{A}\,(x\in A)\}$$

and

$$\bigcap\mathscr{A}=\{x:\forall A\in\mathscr{A}\,(x\in A)\}\;.$$

These definitions specialize to the usual definition of $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$ when $\mathscr{A}$ contains just two sets, and these definitions are independent of any parenthesizing or other organization of the members of $\mathscr{A}$ into smaller subcollections. Thus, the order and grouping of the sets makes no difference to the union and intersection of the family.

Comment: And we guarantee that these definitions are independent of any parenthesizing or some other organization of the members into smaller sub collections because we have the associative law for two sets, right?

Comment: @Andrew: No: we guarantee it because it’s built into the definitions.

Comment: So what's the exact role of the associative law here?

Comment: @Andrew: Where? In what context? I’m afraid that I really don’t yet understand where you see a problem.

Comment: My confusion is the following: the associative law is proved for two sets be the definition of union and intersection

Comment: But these definitions don't state the associative law, it's a consequence of our definition

Comment: Here we are putting the law of the associative directly into the definition?

Comment: @Andrew: Not exactly; it’s simply a trivial consequence of the definition, because no ordering of the sets is involved in any way. $\mathscr{A}$ is just a collection of sets. Those sets aren’t (necessarily) numbers, laid out in line, or otherwise organized.

Comment: Oh now I'm getting the idea! I think it became more clear now! I think the problem here is my notion of order

Comment: @Andrew: I suspect that you’re right. Just think of $\mathscr{A}$ as a bunch of sets all thrown into a bag called $\mathscr{A}$. Then something’s in $\bigcup\mathscr{A}$ if it’s in at least one of those sets, and it’s in $\bigcap\mathscr{A}$ if it’s in all of them.

Comment: Exactly, it's more clear to think that way! Thank you! :)

Comment: @Andrew: You’re welcome!